# Two collection like whole data in user collection and otp_instance field in otp collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

```
const userSchema = new Schema(
  {
    fullName: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
    },
    mobile_number: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
    },
    otp_instance: [{
            otp_id: {
                type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                required: false
            },
            otp: {
                type: String,
                required: false
            },
      createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date()
      },
      expiration_time: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date()
      },
        }],
    resetLink: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
    },
    isAccountVerified: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
    },
    token: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
    },
    activeStatus: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
      default: "0",
    },
    deletedStatus: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
      default: "0",
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
  );
```

This is my schema model. Is this possible to only otp_instance field insert in two collection like whole data in user collection and otp_instance field in otp collection.